# Optional nullable field in Grails command object

Tags: grails

If I have a domain class like so:

```
class Person {
    String phoneNumber
    Book favoriteBook

    static constraints = {
        phoneNumber nullable: false // you must have a phone number
        favoriteBook nullable: true // it is not necessary to have a favorite book
    }
}
```

In this case, it is not required for a person to have a favorite book.

I want to make a command object that would allow users to update their information.

```
class PersonUpdate {
    String phoneNumber
    Book favoriteBook

    static constraints = {
        phoneNumber nullable: false
        favoriteBook nullable: true
    }
}

def updatePerson(PersonUpdate cmd) {
    Person person = ...
    person.phoneNumber = cmd.phoneNumber
    person.favoriteBook = cmd.favoriteBook
    person.save()
}
```

But this would require that they re-specify ALL their information each time they want to make an update. So what I would do is make everything optional:

```
class PersonUpdate {
    String phoneNumber
    Book favoriteBook

    static constraints = {
        phoneNumber nullable: true
        favoriteBook nullable: true
    }
}

def updatePerson(PersonUpdate cmd) {
    Person person = ...
    if (cmd.phoneNumber != null) person.phoneNumber = cmd.phoneNumber
    if (cmd.favoriteBook != null) person.favoriteBook = cmd.favoriteBook
    person.save()
}
```

Now, what happens if the person decides they no longer want to have a favorite book. What they would do is send a JSON payload like so: `{favoriteBook:null}` But this would not do anything since `favoriteBook` is checked to be non-null before updating it.

This generally boils down to the difference between `null` and `undefined`.

So my question is: Is there any way with command objects to have optional nullable fields? And if so, how would I do it to satisfy the above scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep `request.JSON` available so that we can run `containsKey()` on it to test if the request passed the value. Note: putting the command object in the method parameters will consume `request.JSON` and it will be empty.

```
class PersonUpdate implements grails.validation.Validateable {
    String phoneNumber
    Book favoriteBook

    static constraints = {
        phoneNumber nullable: true
        favoriteBook nullable: true
    }
}

def updatePerson() {
    PersonUpdate cmd = new PersonUpdate(request.JSON)
    Person person = ...
    if (request.JSON.containsKey("phoneNumber")) person.phoneNumber = cmd.phoneNumber
    if (request.JSON.containsKey("favoriteBook")) person.favoriteBook = cmd.favoriteBook
    person.save()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually checking, you can associate the properties of the instance of the domain class with the properties of the command object

```
person.properties = cmd.properties
```

I share a controller action with you to verify a case similar to the one that concerns you

```
def update(UpdatePersonCommand command) {
    Person person = Person.get(params.id)

    if (command.hasErrors()) {
        respond ([errors: command.errors], model: [person: person], view: 'edit')

        return
    }

    person.properties = command.properties

    person.save(flush: true)

    redirect action: 'edit', id: params.id
}
```

You can verify a deeper example in this [grails guide](http://guides.grails.org/command-objects-and-forms/guide/index.html) in the section *4.3 Implement the edit and update actions* you will find a similar case

Comment: This does not work. It will set all properties of the domain object to null if an empty JSON payload is sent `{}`. I need all the properties not specified to remain equal to what they were before (they can be updated _optionally_).

Comment: If you pass an empty json it wont validate because of the constraints `phoneNumber nullable: false` in your domain class

Comment: Sure, but then none of the update properties are optional. I want them to be optionally updated.

Comment: So you probably need to set `phoneNumber nullable: true` in both command object and domain class constraints

Comment: That would set `phoneNumber ` to `null` if it is not specified in the update JSON. I want any fields not specified to remain the same as they were before.